# Memory snapshot triggers Garbage collection in dotMemory

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm using dotMemory to profile asp.net mvc application running on IIS.

And I suspect that 'get snapshot' causes GC gen2 to run. Why?
Here is the picture:

[image: Snapshot causes gc]
Question is: is it normal behaivour? Why can't I get snapshot showing me all this uncollected by GC stuff? Every time I gets snapshot: memory usage falls down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal behavior, because it does a full garbage collection before getting a snapshot. If you see memory usage falls down when you get a snapshot, that's a good sign.

Garbage collector cleans memory only if there is a memory stress. If you want to check for memory leaks you have to execute a full garbage collection and get a snapshot. If anything remains that's a memory leak.

Generally you should get a clean base snapshot and then another clean snapshot after you executing the functionality you want to test and then compare both snapshots.

Comment: And this is uncofigurable? I just wanted to see objects arrangement in Large Object Heap. But this objects are alive for short amount of time, so after GC there are only 1-2 of them. Now I understand, why dotMemory is doing GC, thank you for the answer! But in my case I wanted to see how application lives in real life, when GC is not so often.

Comment: @VorobeY1326: I doubt you could see memory map without taking a snapshot. However, if you want, if you could hold a reference to those objects in a way that GC cannot release it. Then you will be able to see it in the LOH.

Comment: Each DotMemory snapshot has a 'memory traffic' link. It allows you to see memory allocations and collections even on objects that have been collected.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft profiling API is working in this way, dotMemory initiates garbage collecting and gathers an object graph during GC.